# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. When using ajax

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, axios

I have REST API which I wrote on Spring Boot.
I want to write a frontend for it using React. To begin with, I decided to make sure that my frontend correctly receives data from the API.

Here is my rest controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/restaurants")
public class RestaurantRestController {
    private final RestaurantService restaurantService;

    public RestaurantRestController(RestaurantService restaurantService) {
        this.restaurantService = restaurantService;
    }

    @GetMapping
//    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('everything:read entries')")
    @ApiOperation("Get all restaurants")
    public ResponseEntity<List<RestaurantDto>> getAll() {
        List<RestaurantDto> result = restaurantService.findAll().stream()
                .map(RestaurantDto::fromRestaurant)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I wrote a configuration class on the backend side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

registry.addMapping("/api/**")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST, "PUT", "DELETE")
        .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);

}
}
```

And I access my controller from the frontend with this method:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const REST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/restaurants";

export default class RestaurantsAPI {

    static async getAll() {
        const response = await axios.get(REST_URL);
        return response.data
    }
}
```

And I get the correct answer.
Then I add credentials to my request:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const REST_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/restaurants";

export default class RestaurantsAPI {

    static async getAll() {
        const response = await axios.get(REST_URL, {
            auth: {
                username: 'admin', password: 'admin'
            }
        });
        return response.data
    }
}
```

Now I see this in the console:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgHoW.jpg)

At the same time, it doesn’t matter, I leave access to the method open to everyone, using this configuration:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/restaurants").permitAll()
```

Or vice versa, I comment this configuration and apply an annotation to the method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('everything:read entries')")
```

I still get the same error.
Thanks to Postman and JUnit Tests, I know that Spring Security is configured and working properly.
Please explain what is the reason for this behavior and what should I do to fix it. Thank you.